# Lua, if statement idiom fails to return proper boolean

Tags: lua

```
local a = (true==true) and false or nil -- returns nil
local a = (true==true) and true or nil -- returns true
local a = (true==true) and not false or nil -- returns true
local a = (true==true) and not true or nil -- returns nil
```

Returns proper `boolean` when value is `true`, but fails when `false`. Why?

Comment: [Programming in Lua: Logical Operators](http://www.lua.org/pil/3.3.html)

Comment: Synopsis: `or` and `and` are not `boolean` operators; They are "Logical Operators". They neither require nor necessarily return `boolean` values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The boolean idiom works by using short-cut evaluation (only evaluate the second operand when necessary).

If you rewrite the expressions with explicit precedence you can see why you would get `nil`:

```
(true and false) or nil     =>  false or nil  => nil
(true and true) or nil      =>  true or nil   => true
(true and not false) or nil =>  true or nil   => true
(true and not true) or nil  =>  false or nil  => nil
```

The [Logical Operators](http://www.lua.org/pil/3.3.html) section of [Programming in Lua](http://www.lua.org/pil/contents.html) explains the idiom:

> Another useful idiom is (a and b) or c (or simply a and b or c, because and has a higher precedence than or), which is equivalent to the C expression
>
> a ? b : c
>
> **provided that b is not false**. For instance, we can select the maximum of two numbers x and y with a statement like
>
> max = (x > y) and x or y

Why can `b` not be `false`? Because the evaluation will always return `false`.

```
1 > 0 and false  --> false
1 < 0 and false  --> false
```